# Golang Decode Nested JSON into Nested Struct

Tags: json, curl, struct, go, nested

Lets look at the following code snippet:

```
type Input struct {
    Value1   string
    Value2   string
    Value3   string
    Value4   string
    Nest         
}

type Nest struct {
    ID  string
}
input := &Input{}
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
if err := decoder.Decode(&input); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("something went wrong %v", err)
}
fmt.Printf("Json Input = %+v\n", input)
```

I'm sending the following via *cURL*:

```
curl -k -vvv  -X POST -d '{"value1":"test", "value2":"Somevalue", "value3":"othervalue", "Nest":{"ID": "12345"}}' http://localhost:8000/endpoint
```

.. and get the following output:

```
{Value1:test Value2:Somevalue Value3:othervalue Value4: Nest:{ID:}}
```

**Problem:**

I'm not getting a good decoding of the nested struct for some reason. Moreover, I'm not really sure if it's my code or the way I'm calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Nest` is [embedded](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) in `Input`.

The JSON `{"value1":"test", "value2":"Somevalue", "value3":"othervalue", "ID": "12345"}` will be correctly marshalled into your `Input`.

If you want to use the JSON body from your Question then you will have to change `Input` to the following

```
type Input struct {
    Value1   string
    Value2   string
    Value3   string
    Value4   string
    Nest     Nest    
}
```

Comment: Strange, I thought I had tried that already.  It did work this time though.  Thanks!